# how to get data firebase collection in collection

Tags: javascript, angular, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, angularfire2

I want to get data in collection 'action'

```
ticket
  ->document in ticket collection(id)
    ->**action**
      ->document in action collection(id) 
         -> data
```

[image]

[image]

I have .ts and service but I don't know how get data display in .html

app.html

```
<div class="row" *ngFor="let action of Action">
   *<!-- {{ action.payload.doc }} -->
   <!-- {{ getAction(action) }} -->*
</div>
```

app.ts

```
  ngOnInit() {
    this.auth.user$.subscribe(user => this.user = user)
    this.ticket$ = this.ticketService.getTicketByid(this.id);
    this.action = this.ticketService.getTrack(this.id).snapshotChanges().subscribe(data => {
      data.map(items => {
        const item = items.payload.doc.data();
        const id = items.payload.doc.id;
        return { id, ...item };
      })
    })
  }
```

app.service

```
  getTrack(id: string): any {
    return this.afs.collection('ticket').doc(id)
      .collection('action', ref => ref
        .orderBy('date', 'desc'))
  }
```

Comment: At the very least you seem to have a mismatch in case between `*ngFor="let action of Action">` and `this.action = this.ticketService.getTrack(this.id).snapshotChanges()...`. I recommend naming the collection as plural, so `this.actions = this.ticketService.getTrack(this.id).snapshotChanges()` and `*ngFor="let action of actions">`

Answer (score 2):

Please use below code for get the child data from firestore.

```
getTrack(id: string){
    let docRef = this.fireservices.collection('ticket');
    const tickets = docRef.snapshotChanges().pipe(
       map((actions) =>
         actions.map((a) => {
           //this.parentId is your parent documentId
           this.parentId = a.payload.doc.id;
           return docRef.doc(id).collection('action').valueChanges();
         })
       )
     );
     tickets.subscribe(data => {
       data[0].subscribe(child => {
         //Here you can get the child data
         console.log(child[0]);
       });
     });
}
```

Comment: this is your service getTrack funtion

Comment: I have commented in code where you can got the child data

Comment: you can return the const tickets variable from service and in your component.ts you can subscribed.

Comment: my service getTrack funtion doesn't work?

Comment: You are asking about get data of collection into collection right?

Comment: Use my code you will got the data from firestore collection into collection

Comment: excuse me what's 'parentId'? is variable right?

Comment: Yes this is my working code it was added by mistake

Comment: @tixxff Did the answer work for you? If indeed it worked, please be kind enough to accept the answer to help other users to get solutions for their questions.

Comment: I can did it but isn't this answer

Comment: Yes sure you can